# Linq To SQL Attach/Refresh Entity Object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

In Linq To Sql, when updating one of my entities, Faculty, I am creating a new instance of the Faculty object, then initializing *some* of the properties with values supplied by the user.

If I attach this new object to the entity set, and submit changes, the properties that I didn't set take on the default value of whatever datatype they are.

How can I refresh the new object so that the properties that have been set keep their values and the properties that haven't been set get the values from the database?

Thanks

Comment: just out of curiosity, are the null types "GUID"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try

`context.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, faculty);`

after submit changes where `context` is your linq2sql datacontext and `faculty` is the entity you want to refresh?

Comment: I've noticed it's also needed to do `yourBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();` if you're refreshing the entity outside of the `CurrentChanged` event of the binding source.

Answer (score 1):

What about retrieving the object from the database, then changing the appropriate values, then submitting the update?

Comment: I am maintaining some code that uses the attach method, and I am not quite sure why it wasn't written to do what you suggest to begin with.

Comment: I think he is referring to creating a new entry in a table.

Comment: Oh! Now I remember. It's because there is a timestamp field called version. Doing what you suggested causes this error:  Value of member 'Version' of an object of type 'Faculty' changed. A member that is computed or generated by the database cannot be changed.

Comment: How is the date put in?  Is it a default?  I am confused why you would not be able to change a timestamp in the database.