# LINQ to SQL Attaching collection of object from XML file Database

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am developing an HRM application to import and export xml data from database. The application receives exported xml data for the employee entry. I imported the xml file using linq to xml, where I converted the xml into respective objects. Then I want to attach (update) the employee objects.

I tried to use

```
//linqoper class for importing xml data and converts into IEnumerable employees object.
  var emp = linqoper.importxml(filename.xml);
  Using (EmployeedataContext  db = new EmployeedatContext){
  db.attachAllonSubmit(emp);
  db.submitchange();
 }
```

But I got error 
`“An entity can only be attached as modified without  original state if it declares as version member or doesn't have an update check policy”`.

I have also an option to retrieve each employee, and assign value to the new employee from xml data using this format.

```
//import IEnumerable of Employee objects
var employees = = linqoper.importxml(filename.xml)
using(Employeedatacontext db = new Employeedatacontext){
foreach(var empobj  in employees)
{
 Employee emp = db.Employee.where(m=>m.id==empobj.Id);
emp.FirstName=empobj.FirstName;
emp.BirthDate=empobj.BirthDate;
//….continue 
}
db.submitChanges();
}
```

But the problem with the above is I have to iterate through the whole employee objects, which is very tiresome. 
So is there any other way, I could attach (update) the employee entity in the database using LINQ to SQL.

I have seen some similar links on SO, but none of them seems to help.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898267/linq-to-sql-attach-refresh-entity-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898267/linq-to-sql-attach-refresh-entity-object/%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898267/linq-to-sql-attach-refresh-entity-object%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linq-to-sql saves the changes to the database, it has to know properties of the object has been changed. It also checks if a potentially conflicting update to the database have been done during the update (optimistic concurrency).

To handle those cases LINQ-to-SQL needs two copies of the object when attaching. One with the original values (as present in the DB) and one with the new, changed values. There is also a more advanced mechanism involving a version member which is mapped to a `rowversion` column.

The linq-to-sql way to update a set of data is to first read all data from the database, then update the objects retrieved form the database and finally call `SubmitChanges()`. That would be my first approach in your situation.

If you experience performance problems, then it's time to go outside of linq-to-sql's toolbox. A solution with better performance is to load the new data into a separate staging table (for best performance, use bulk insert). Then run a SQL command or Stored Procedure that does the actual merging of data. The SQL `Merge` clause is excellent for this kind of updates.

Comment: Thank you @Anders-Abel, So do you mean there is no way to attach a collection of object ripped from XML file using the attach method in LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL is proper ORM, but if you want to take control of create/update/delete in your hand; than you can try some simple ORMs which just provide ways to do CRUD operations. I can recommend one http://crystalmapper.codeplex.com, it is simple yet powerful.

Why CrystalMapper?

I built this for large financial transaction system with lots of insert and update operations. What I need is speed and control of insert/update serving complex business scenarios ... hitting multiple tables just for one transaction.

When I put this to use in social text processing platform, it serves very well there too.